# How to unzip all the password protected zip files in a directory using Java

Tags: java, zip, unzip, password-protection

I am new to java and trying to write an program which will unzip all the password protected zip files in an directory, I am able to unzip all the normal zip files (Without password) but I am not sure how to unzip  password protected files.
Note: All zip files have same password

```
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.PathMatcher;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.stream.Stream;
import java.util.zip.ZipEntry;
import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.FileHeader;

import java.util.zip.*;

public class Extraction {
    // public Extraction() {
    //
    // try {
    //
    // ZipFile zipFile = new
    // ZipFile("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ZipFile\\myzip.zip");
    //
    // if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
    //
    // zipFile.setPassword("CLAIMS!");
    // }
    //
    // List fileHeaderList = zipFile.getFileHeaders();
    //
    // for (int i = 0; i < fileHeaderList.size(); i++) {
    // FileHeader fileHeader = (FileHeader) fileHeaderList.get(i);
    //
    // zipFile.extractFile(fileHeader, "C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ZipFile");
    // System.out.println("Extracted");
    // }
    //
    // } catch (Exception e) {
    // System.out.println("Please Try Again");
    // }
    //
    // }
    //
    // public static void main(String[] args) {
    // new Extraction();
    //
    // }
    // }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Extraction unzipper = new Extraction();
        unzipper.unzipZipsInDirTo(Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ZipFile"),
                Paths.get("C:\\Users\\Desktop\\ZipFile\\Unziped"));

    }

    public void unzipZipsInDirTo(Path searchDir, Path unzipTo) {

        final PathMatcher matcher = searchDir.getFileSystem().getPathMatcher("glob:**/*.zip");
        try (final Stream<Path> stream = Files.list(searchDir)) {
            stream.filter(matcher::matches).forEach(zipFile -> unzip(zipFile, unzipTo));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Something went wrong, Please try again!!");
        }
    }

    public void unzip(Path zipFile, Path outputPath) {
        try (ZipInputStream zis = new ZipInputStream(Files.newInputStream(zipFile))) {

            ZipEntry entry = zis.getNextEntry();

            while (entry != null) {

                Path newFilePath = outputPath.resolve(entry.getName());
                if (entry.isDirectory()) {
                    Files.createDirectories(newFilePath);
                } else {
                    if (!Files.exists(newFilePath.getParent())) {
                        Files.createDirectories(newFilePath.getParent());
                    }
                    try (OutputStream bos = Files.newOutputStream(outputPath.resolve(newFilePath))) {
                        byte[] buffer = new byte[Math.toIntExact(entry.getSize())];

                        int location;

                        while ((location = zis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
                            bos.write(buffer, 0, location);
                        }
                    }
                }
                entry = zis.getNextEntry();
            }
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            System.out.println("Please try again");
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I found the answer I am posting this as there might be someone else who might be looking for the similar answer.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.List;

import javax.swing.filechooser.FileNameExtensionFilter;

import net.lingala.zip4j.core.ZipFile;
import net.lingala.zip4j.model.FileHeader;

public class SamExtraction {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        final FileNameExtensionFilter extensionFilter = new FileNameExtensionFilter("N/A", "zip");
        //Folder where zip file is present
        final File file = new File("C:/Users/Desktop/ZipFile");
        for (final File child : file.listFiles()) {
            try {
                ZipFile zipFile = new ZipFile(child);
                if (extensionFilter.accept(child)) {
                    if (zipFile.isEncrypted()) {
                        //Your ZIP password
                        zipFile.setPassword("MYPASS!");
                    }
                    List fileHeaderList = zipFile.getFileHeaders();

                    for (int i = 0; i < fileHeaderList.size(); i++) {
                        FileHeader fileHeader = (FileHeader) fileHeaderList.get(i);
                        //Path where you want to Extract
                        zipFile.extractFile(fileHeader, "C:/Users/Desktop/ZipFile");
                        System.out.println("Extracted");
                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Please Try Again");
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanx a lot! u helped me!