# Opening password protected RAR files in Java

Tags: java

I've been searching Google for some time now but can't seem to find any library that allows me to open password protected RAR files using Java (compressed files).

If anyone knows of one please share it with me (if possible one including a maven dependency).

I've been looking at JUnRar and java-UnRar, but both do not support password protected files for as far as I could discover.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to unzip all the password protected zip files in a directory using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44985323/how-to-unzip-all-the-password-protected-zip-files-in-a-directory-using-java)

Comment: @Tarun Not a duplicate. I am trying to unpack a rar file not a zip file.

Comment: @PietHein, I wonder if you stumbled over any additional solutions, libraries etc. while researching your problem?

Comment: @MaximilianC. I abandoned this little project. Best I could find is what you suggested. To make it portable to other operating systems all I could think of was to let the user input a link on the filesystem to a unrar application from rarlab. But as mentioned I abandoned the project and moved on to learning other things.

Answer (score 4):

WinRAR is shipped with two utility programs (unrar.exe and rar.exe). From Powershell, you can unrar an archive by calling: `unrar e .\my-archive.rar -p[your-password]`

Now, you could place this call using the `exec()` method of Java's Runtime class:

```
public class UnArchiver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {        
        try {   
            String command = "unrar.exe e .\my-archive.rar -pQWERT";
            Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command); 
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
    }
}
// Code not tested
```

However, this option has some drawbacks:

- Password is handled as string (bad practice when handling password)
- I do not know how `exec()` is implemented for Windows JVMs. I think there is a risk the password ends up in an unsafe place (log file?) where it does not belong.
- For me, `exec()` always has a smell to it (because it introduces coupling to the environment - in this case `unrar.exe` that is not visible on first glance for later maintainers of your code)
- You introduce a platform dependency (in this case to Windows) as `unrar.exe` can run only on Windows (thanks @SapuSeven)

Note: When searching on Stackoverflow.com, you probably stumbled over the [Junrar](https://github.com/junrar/junrar) library. It cannot be used to extract encrypted archives (see line 122 of [this file](https://github.com/junrar/junrar/blob/cc856dbf7c475ef4eccd3b16da2d744fb2043019/src/main/java/com/github/junrar/Junrar.java)).

Comment: I also really dislike and recommend not using exec in Java at all (maybe in some rare cases). Not only do you effectively remove platform independence (a big strength of Java) but you also rely on third party programs, which are not even open source (which is generally a bad idea).

Comment: I feel similar regarding `exec()`. Obviously, you are right in regards of platform dependency and coupling. However, I'd like to point out the following: As to my knowledge, WinRAR is a proprietary piece of software and proprietary format. As a consequence it might become more difficult to find a solution with an OSI conforming OS license...

Answer (score 1):

SevenZip library could extract many types of archive files including RAR

```
        randomAccessFile= new RandomAccessFile(sourceZipFile, "r");
    inArchive = SevenZip.openInArchive(null, // autodetect archive type
            new RandomAccessFileInStream(randomAccessFile));
    simpleInArchive = inArchive.getSimpleInterface();

    for (int i = 0; i < inArchive.getNumberOfItems(); i++) {
        ISimpleInArchiveItem archiveItem = simpleInArchive.getArchiveItem(i);

        final File outFile = new File(destFolder,archiveItem.getPath());
        outFile.getParentFile().mkdirs();
        logger.debug(String.format("extract(%s) in progress: %s",sourceZipFile.getName(),archiveItem.getPath()));
        final BufferedOutputStream out=new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(outFile));
        ExtractOperationResult result = archiveItem.extractSlow(new ISequentialOutStream() {
            public int write(byte[] data) throws SevenZipException {
                try {
                    out.write(data);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new SevenZipException(String.format("error in writing extracted data from:%s to:%s ",sourceZipFile.getName(),outFile.getName()),e);
                }finally{
                    try{out.close();}catch(Exception e){}
                }
                return data.length; // return amount of consumed data
            }
        });
        if(result!=ExtractOperationResult.OK){
            throw new SevenZipException(String.format(" %s error occured in extracting : %s item of file : %s ",result.name(),archiveItem.getPath(),sourceZipFile.getName()));
        }
    }
```